# jquery access element inside iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have a page which has an `iframe` element inside it. This iFrame contains two levels of `document` inside it.

Here is the short version of code (removed most of stuff as otherwise it would be too big)

```
<iframe src="some soruce" width="863" height="486" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
    <html>
        <head>...</head>
          <body>
              <iframe id="player" src="some source" width="863" height="486" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
                <html>
                    <head>...</head>
                    <body>
                      <div id="mediaplayer_wrapper" style="position: relative; width: 863px; height: 486px;">
                        <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="/new-flash-player/player.swf" width="100%" height="100%" id="mediaplayer" name="mediaplayer" tabindex="0"></div></div>
                      <div id="banners_area" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 863px; height: 486px; display: none; background-color: white;">
                              <br>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    </body>
                </html>             
              </iframe>
        </body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

What I am trying to do, is to access via jQuery the `mediaplayer` object and trigger a function on it. I have tried the following:

```
var p = jQuery("mediaplayer");
p.hideGate();
```

and also

```
var p = $("#iFrame").contents().find("#mediaplayer");
p.hideGate();
```

but none of them have worked. (gave me an error that `hideGate` is not defined. However when under developer I switch myself to the content of that particular player, and execute the very first code, it suddenly works.

[image]

What am I doing wrong here? How come I cannot trigger the function?

Comment: Do you have access to all these documents?

Comment: You have #player iframe  embedded inside outer iframe with src="some soruce". That's strange since the content of the outer iframe will be whatever is in "some soruce" and not what you've written inline in your code. Thus the inner iframe #player will not be accessible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hideGate` is not a standard jQuery method. It must be provided by a plugin.

You have multiple documents, and that plugin is loaded into the version of jQuery that is in the framed document with the #mediaplayer element in it.

When you call jQuery from the parent frame, you are using the version of jQuery there … which **doesn't** have the plugin installed.

You can probably solve this by loading the plugin script into the document in the parent frame.

Failing that, you would need to call the `jQuery` function from the document in the frame. (Possibly `$("#iFrame")[0].contentWindow.jQuery("#mediaplayer")` would do that, but I don't have time to write a test case to be sure right now).

Comment: seems like this has actually worked. Even though it states that I am blocked, it clearly found it. I am basically getting `blocked a frame with origin from accessing a cross-origin frame`

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you want to try the **.contentWindow** property as shown in: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_frame_contentwindow.asp

Hope it helps.

Comment: No. The OP is using jQuery, and have already found `contents()` which is the equivalent for that library.